# Run explorer.exe elevated/as Administrator user within Windows 10

Tags: explorer, administrator, elevated-privileges

How can explorer.exe be run elevated/with full admin token/permissions in windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Via task manager:

1. Kill all instances of explorer.exe
2. File > Run new task
3. `explorer /nouaccheck`
4. **Create this task with administrative privileges**
5. OK

[Source 1 (in the comments)](http://woshub.com/how-to-run-file-explorer-elevated/)
[Source 2](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/79917-whats-createexplorershellunelevatedtask.html)